# Choosing native Apple or Google Maps SDK for iOS app

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

This is a less programmatic and more service related question. 
 
     I used apple native maps API which integrated google maps service before iOS6 independent apple maps release. So now I am confused between selecting Apple & Google Map. 
   After last year maps problem Apple seem to improve a lot but is it worth using Apple native maps over more reliable Gmaps (for any location)?
    
   I need to integrate map service into a navigational service, so I need to make a decision between the two to use for development. 
    
   Pros n cons are welcomed by ones who have experienced using both (iOS7 maps N Google Maps SDK for iOS).
    
    Thank you in advance!!

[Note: I have seen other similar links but they are not extensive in app's final experience n output]

Comment: Just one point... Google maps for iOS SDK has low frame rate on iOS. So if you want to show an interactive map to user, it may lag and downgrade the user experience a little (especially when they are using iPhone 4/4S). Some developers have suggested Google to improve this, but as for now, it looks like there is still some time to wait...

Comment: Depends on your needs...my app depends on using a pretty high zoom level, and Apple maps is a bit limited in this respect. Google Maps lets me zoom further, so that's what I went with.

Answer (score 1):

It really can depend on what sort of navigation you are doing and what sort of app you are building. Are you doing realtime routing? Using your own routing data? Do you need offline capabilities? You might also consider a framework like [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk).

Comment: Yes, I need maps to display (stored) data even if the user is offline,

Answer (score 1):

For me the decision to use Google maps was based on the need to use Google services, Places in particular. If you are using Google services, the license dictates that you must use them with Google maps. I imagine the same would be true for Apple services and Apple maps but since Apple doesn't really have any services to speak of (for now), it's not an issue.