# MapKit or Google Maps SDK? (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I am doing an app that requires a map with markers (which includes address and pictures) and possibly a GPS.  I am feeding the data (address and pictures) from Parse database, and I am developing for iOS... I have heard that native is better, but I am a huge fan of google and google maps.  Which one would you recommend?  Mapkit or GoogleMaps?  What is the benefit of one over the other?

Thank you.
Josh

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of off site resources are off topic.

Comment: have a look over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567084/choosing-native-apple-or-google-maps-sdk-for-ios-app

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `MapKit` has a much better integration with `CoreLocation` and
>   `CoreAnimation`. The “Follow user location” mode is missing in Google
>   Maps; as well, the ability to add advanced animations to annotations
>   (`MKAnnotation` is represented by a `UIView`, while a `GMSMarker` is
>   represented by a `UIImage`) can give your app an appealing touch that
>   the Google Maps SDK just can’t.

from http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift.

As you are going to show address and picture on the marker, so [Apple's Map Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html) will be better option to work with.

Comment: This no longer appears to be accurate - GMSMarker now has an `iconView` property (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#use_the_markers_iconview_property).